# should we always replace for loops with list comprehension

Tags: python, for-loop, generator, list-comprehension

my question is just as the title.

1. Should we always try to replace a for loop with list/dict comprehension when we can since the latter performs faster?

I am writing this project which requires iterating through some massive lists of tuples several times and it's taking forever. So I am struggling to optimize my codes now. The main reason I need to iterate through a list of tuples is, assume I have a value, I'd like to know if it is in the list and what is the other value in the same tuple.

2. is turning these lists into an array or dictionary would help?

Any input will be much appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you looked into generators? It sounds like in your scenario there is really no need to create a list before iterating.

Comment: And please show us your code!

Comment: That's a bit broad. It would be best to show a minimal example of the list of tuples you loop through along with your desired outcome and current implementation. Then one can think about how to optimize this.

Comment: If you code takes forever now, it will still take forever with list comprehension -- maybe a bit more or less, but it's still O(forever). Change your algorithm or data structures instead.

Comment: If you're actually try to construct a list, a list comprehension might improve your code. Otherwise, a list comprehension is _not_ a replacement for a for loop.

Comment: List comprehension is generally more compact and faster than normal functions and loops for creating a list.
However, we should avoid writing very long list comprehensions in one a line to ensure that code is user-friendly.

Answer (score 5):

Using a dictionary instead of a list of tuples would be MUCH more efficient- in general, getting a value from a dictionary for a given key is O(1) (constant speed, doesn't matter how big the dict is), while going through an entire list searching for a tuple is O(n) (which means that the efficiency goes down as the list grows).

List comprehension instead of for loops shouldn't make a big difference, aside from the fact that in list comprehension you're actually building a list- so you could have memory issues if the loop you're going through is very large.

It sounds like you should have a dict in this scenario- btw- to convert a list of tuples to a dict, just do:

`dict(list_of_tuples)`